# Usar array PHP e trazer resultados em varias linhas

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma array `$_POST['form']['clima']` que neste exemplo tem o valor abaixo

```
array(2){
[0]=> string(1) "1"
[1]=> string(1) "2"
}
```

Eu preciso pegar esses valores para juntar com o $id (nesse exemplo será 3) para trazer o resultado abaixo ($id, valor de cada array):

```
(3, 1),
(3, 2)
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Tentei assim, mas repetiu o valor 2:

```
$id = 3;
foreach($_POST['form']['clima'] as $clima){
$todos = '('.$id.','.$clima.')';
$todos.=','.$todos;
}
```

Resultado do que fiz:

```
(3,2),(3,2)
```

Comment: Poderia descrever **na pergunta** o que tentou fazer e o resultado obtido?

Comment: opa, coloquei la o que fiz

Comment: Você está sobrescrevendo a variável `$todos` dentro do laço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está sobrescrevendo a variável `$todos` dentro do seu lado, descartando os valores antigos:

```
$id = 3;

foreach($_POST['form']['clima'] as $clima){
    $todos = '('.$id.','.$clima.')';  // ERRADO
    $todos.=','.$todos;
}
```

Você precisa utilizar variáveis diferentes ou concatenar de forma direta:

```
$id = 3;
$todos = '';

foreach ($_POST['form']['clima'] as $clima) {
    $todos .= '('.$id.','.$clima.')';
}
```

Mas o mais simples é utilizar a função `array_map`:

```
$todos = join(',', array_map(function ($clima) use ($id) {
    return "({$id}, {$clima})";
}, $_POST['form']['clime']);
```

Comment: deu certinho, só alterei, o ultimo clima vc escreveu clime e faltou fechar um parenteses por último, aí deu certinho o array_map, obrigado!

Comment: Só para agregar, join é um apelido para implode http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php